# MySQL select parents and child all from on table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have one table that holds parent pages and sub pages, where top page is parent_id = 0 and subpage parent_id is the id of as other page.

```
ID 1 | parent_id 0
ID 2 | parent_id 0
ID 3 | Parent_id 1
ID 4 | parent_id 1
ID 5 | parent_id 0
```

So I have

```
SELECT *
FROM pages AS parent
WHERE parent.parent_id = 0

SELECT *
FROM pages AS sub
WHERE sub.parent_id != 0
```

The above separate query's work. But i'm sure there is a may to list all pages with one query.

I'm trying to get a list similar to this, grouping sub pages to the parent page

```
Main (Title1)
Main (Title2)
     SUB (Title1)
     SUB (Tible2)
Main (Title3)
etc
```

I've been trying my luck with inner join and left join but I can't solve this.

I has hoping a kind soul with some experience will give me a hand. :)

Thanks

Comment: I would recommend looking at the groupby function of SQL.  If you list some things you've tried (actual code) then someone can tweak that for you.

Comment: `select * from yourtable` will list everything. If you want it in a tree structure, that's up to you. SQL doesn't do "trees". it does sets of data.

Comment: When you have the indentation before "SUB" in your desired output... what does that represent? Does it mean you want the mySQL result somehow formatted that way? 'Cause that can't happen. Does it just mean you want the results ordered the way your desired output is ordered? 'Cause that's doable, but it would require some crazy shenanigans in SQL to pull off. You'd be much better pulling everything out and doing the work in PHP.

Comment: Hello. Yes I do what to get the listing in a "tree" like manner. In php I i'm pulling what I need with two querys and loops. I was looking for a way to do the same with one query and one loop with a optimized query. That was the my aim any way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following query, It has additional column page_type which indicates page type.

`SELECT page.* , IF(
(SELECT p.parent_id FROM pages p WHERE p.id = page.id) = 0, "PARENT", "CHILD"
) AS PAGE_TYPE 
FROM pages AS page`

Comment: Hi. Thanks for sharing your Knowledge. This does what I asked. Is there a way, for the child records do come after the parent record? shorting them like father > son | father | etc

Comment: Order by on parent_id can be used to sort the records, so that child record comes after the parent records... e.g. `From pages as page order by page.parent_id asc`

Comment: Hi. What I mean, is can I get parent, then childs, then another parent again and childs if exists, then parent and so on... until list is complete?

Comment: In this scenario if multiple parents are at the same level and each have multiple children, then does all parents should be listed first and after that all children should be listed or first parent and all its childs and then second parent and all its child??

Comment: Hi. I would like it be list father then children of that father. Then the next father and children for that father. And so on... With php and some loops I have done it with your suggested mysql code. So its not really needed anymore but I would like to know if it can be done and how using only mysql.

Comment: Ohh.. that seems to be difficult and currently I am not finding the way to solve this :(. I will give it a thought though.

Comment: I truly appreciate your efforts. But with the initial query and some php I figured a way to get what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a null check and a `LEFT JOIN` to itself:

```
SELECT IF(parent.ID IS NULL, 'MAIN', 'SUB') as grouping, page.*, parent.*
FROM pages as page
LEFT JOIN pages as parent
ON page.parent_id = parent.ID
```